# How to send notifications to iOS and Android using Python

Tags: python-3.x, push-notification

I have created some code for sending alerts, for now only by emails. I was wondering if there is an easy way to send push notifications to iOS and Android mobiles using Python. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting device tokens from the devices (iOS / Android), and without a valid APNS certificate for the iOS app, there is no way to send push notification to any app.

For iOS, device token and certificate is must.

For Android, a Firebase project has to be setup, and the device token has to be fetched from the app.

If you are the owner of the backend that the mobile apps are using, it is easy to send device tokens from the apps provided you have access to the Firebase project (for Android) and the certificate used (for iOS).

Comment: thanks for your reply. What about if you have the tokens?Are you familiar with Pushsafer?

Comment: In any app (Pushsafer, etc.), for iOS, even if you have the token, you will need the certificate to be able to send pushes. The certificate is used to communicate with Apple Notification Server.